# Where does the term Wud come from?

Tags: wizard-barristers

In the series *Wizard Barristers: Benmashi Cecil*, magic users are often referred to as Wuds.

What does this term mean? Is it an acronym or an abbreviation?
Or is it supposed to be some other thing?

Comment: It's likely to be a shorten version of ウィザード (Wizard) -> ウド (Wud). It could also be a throwback to the expression  独活の大木 (うどのたいぼく、"Good for nothing").

Comment: Wanna write up an answer for this, @ʞɹɐzǝɹ? Or do you feel you don't have enough material to go on from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is likely to be an abbreviation for Wizard (ウィザード), but there is a bit of allusion behind the name.

It is a tricky one to explain and requires a bit of exploration into the Japanese language.

There exists [an expression](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/u/udonotaiboku.html) there, "[うどの大木](http://kakuyasu-eigo.com/greattreesaregoodfor/):"

> "Great trees are good for nothing but shade."
>
> 大きな木々は、日陰以外には役にたたない

This refers to the [Japanese spikenard (known as 独活, "udo"), or "mountain asparagus,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aralia_cordata) referring to how the older, larger plant being of no use, except when it is young (and tender), where it is typically [used for consumption](https://scottishforestgarden.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/growing-and-eating-udo-aralia-cordata/) in cuisine)

It's likely that the creator used the expression to allude to the state of Wizards in the series' universe, useless (good for nothing) fellows (as mentioned by certain character within the series).

There is speculation that there might be even more uses of allusion, but there are no solid sources to corroborate it:

> オズ (o-zu, as in *Wizard of Oz*) → オヅ (o-du, or o-zu, depending on romanization) → ウド (u-do, translated as "Wud")